# Google Cloud Storage change notifications with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have Firebase storage bucket and I would like to use Node.js Google-cloud notification API in order to listen to changes in the storage.

What I have so far:

```
const gcloud = require('google-cloud');

const storage = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'projectId',
  credentials: serviceAccount
});  

const storageBucket = storage.bucket('bucketId');
```

Now from what I understand I have to create a channel in order to listen to storage changes.

So I have:

```
const storageBucketNotificationChannel = storage.channel('channelId', 'resourceId');
```

This is the threshold where the docs stop being clear, as I can't figure out what *channelId* a *resourceId* stand for.

Nor do I understand how to declare listening to channel changes itself. Are there any lifecycle-type methods to do so?

Can I do something like?

```
storageBucketNotificationChannel.onMessage(message => { ... })
```

Comment: Most users use the [gsutil notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification) command to set up the notification channel. Do you need to do it progammatically?

Comment: Yes I do. The reason is that I need an image processing server. I would love to utilize the power of Firebase and make the server "proxied" by Firebase (hidden behind Firebase). Thus I would like the server to listen to storage changes and process the images ad-hoc, on child_added, resp. child_changed.

I did find a solution for my use-case by bridging the problem over Firebase Realtime Database, as Firebase admin Node.js SDK makes it pretty simple to set up the queries I mentioned. 

But as it's not direct answer to the question, I'm leaving the thread open.

Comment: You'll really want to try out Google Cloud Functions (https://cloud.google.com/functions), which simplifies this a ton. See https://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs for an example of how to handle Firebase Storage uploads and process the image.

Comment: I would also highly recommend looking into Google Cloud Functions as it would likely serve the purpose you seek and essentially runs on Node/NPM.  The documentation for channels in the gcloud Node SDK is indeed slim.  I'll see what I can do to test this out possibly get an example running.  I'll bring it up with our documentation team.

Comment: I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1866) to the documentation requesting an example be added to the reference.  Feel free to support this submission if it is important to you.  In the meantime, I'll have to get a valid SSL cert to test this myself since [this is a requirement](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorize_Endpoint) for the receiving endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the existing [documentation of the Google Cloud Node.js Client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.5.0/storage/channel) and the feedback from [this Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1866), there is presently no way for the node client to create a channel or subscribe to object change notifications.

One of the reasons being that the machine using the client may not necessarily be the machine on which the application runs, and thus a security risk.  One can still however, subscribe to object change notifications for a given bucket and have notifications received a Node.js GAE application.

### Using Objects: watchAll JSON API

When using `gsutil` to subscribe, gsutil [sends a POST request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Watching) to `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/watch` where `bucket` is the name of the bucket to be watched.  This is essentially a wrapper around the [JSON API Objects: watchAll](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/watchAll).  Once a desired application/endpoint has been authorized as described in [Notification Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization), one can send the appropriate POST request to said API and provide the desired endpoint URL in `address`.  For instance, `address` could be `https://my-node-app.example.com/change`.

The Node/Express application service would then need to listen to POST requests to path `/change` for [notifications resembling this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Notification_Types).  The application would then act upon that data accordingly.  Note, the application should respond to the request as described in [Reliable Delivery](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery) for Cloud Storage to retry if it failed or stop retrying if it succeeded.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of this working? I am trying to debug a firebase Cloud Function and hoping to replicate the `require('firebase-functions').storage.onChange` event locally in node. This seems like the right track.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors?  What have you tried?  Depending on the content, this may be worth its own question.